# NHibernate upgrade to / downgrade from subclass

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We are mapping the following domain objects using Table-per-subclass mapping:

```
class User {
    Id;
    FirstName;
    LastName;
    etc.
}

class Manager : User {
    // manager specific properties
}
```

When a new `User` is created in the UI we check to see if the `Manager` role has been selected and if necessary create (and save) an instance of `Manager` rather than `User`.

The goal is to make the process of converting a `User` to/from a `Manager` as simple as possible (by just selecting a role).

When I attempt to downgrade a `Manager` to a `User` by removing the `Manager` NHibernate throws an exception because it is attempting to remove the  `User` record as well (which has  constraints on the Roles table).

Similarly I'm not sure how I can "upgrade" a user to `Manager`. Since I can't up-cast I'm guessing I would need to create a new `Manager` instance with the same identity as the existing `User`?

My subclass mapping for `Manager` can be seen below:

```
public class ManagerMap : SubclassMap<Manager>
{
    public ManagerMap()
    {
        Table("Managers");
        KeyColumn("UserId");
        Map(n => n.EmploymentType);
        Map(n => n.PriorityLevel);
    }
}
```

Comment: NHibernate maps objects to/from a relational database. Can you change the type of an object in memory? No. Therefore NHibernate doesn't have any provisions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say this just isn't possible. I tried to do something similar couple of years ago and queried a few people to see if they knew, being heavy NHibernate Users. Conclusion was it's just not possible.

The only solution me or anyone I knew could come up with was to manually update the discriminator in the database using direct SQL.

Assuming a User could only be of 1 type.

i.e Manager, or Employee, or Trainee.

I would give a list of users with a drop-down that allows the user type to be changed. So it was a separate process from 'editing' a user.

This allowed both upgrading/downgrading a user. With the downside of making it a two step process for managing users.

Comment: You may also need to remember to null any columns in DB that are not part of manager and adding columns that are part of user, however it might not be relevant to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad idea to use inheritance here to make a user a Manager. It will get tricky when users fulfil multiple roles. I would add a nullable ManagerBehaviour property to the User class, and eventually maybe move to having a bag of Behaviour objects on the user.

Comment: In our application the only role that has any additional behaviour is `Manager` and attempting to generalize these as behaviours would undoubtably introduce much more complexity.

Comment: One man's complexity is another's simplicity I think! IMO a ManagerBehaviour property is easier than the accepted solution.

Comment: Perhaps, based on the simplified example I posted. However, since `Manager` has a number of one-to-many and one-to-one associations with other objects in our domain, it would be very difficult to turn this into something that is generic.

Comment: I agree with @mcintyre321.  Regardless of the ORM, you cannot change the type of an object at runtime, so inheritance is the wrong way to model this.  You'd be better served with a one-to-one relationship between User and Manager.  You can keep the same table schema, and not break the .NET OO rules.